# How to place a legend right next to the data set (series) on SQL Reporting Services 2008 (SSRS) line chart?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I believe that placing legend at the end of line series is user friendlier rather than placing legend in the table. I do not think SSRS is able to do that...

I could put the series names manually; however, I wish them to be dynamic.

Please advise if you know how to put legend next to the series line as in example below:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click on the values for the chart data
2. In the properties toolbar go to Labels - Label -Label
3. Put the text you want for the label
4. Click the drop down on visible (it is several fields below label)
5. Click expression
6. Put in the logic to only show it if it is the rightmost part on the x axis. For example, if the X axis is a date field make it only show for the max date.

   =IIF(Fields!CreatedOn.Value = MAX(Fields!CreatedOn.Value, "DataSet1"), TRUE, FALSE)

Here is what I end up with:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. I had no idea how to do it when I first read your question. Luckily I was able to figure out a way to get what you need. I may also end up doing this on some of my reports in the future.